# ListBox keeps returning selected index as -1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I try and find the selected item within my listbox it keeps returning -1 as the selected index.  This code is executed within a button click event

int test = Convert.ToInt32(lbProjects.SelectedIndex.ToString());

String number = lbProjects.Items[test].Value;

I am trying to find the value of the selected item within my listbox and in order to do this I need the index of that selected item but when I debug it keeps returning -1 no matter what item I select.  Is there anything I am doing wrong or is it something to do with the way I have populated the list box?

ListBox Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String Sql = @" select * from project";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DA.Fill(DS, "Project");
    DataTable DT = DS.Tables["Project"];

    lbProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
    lbProjects.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
    lbProjects.DataSource = DT;
    lbProjects.DataBind();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldnt be - at what point are you triggering the first set of code? what event on the listbox are you using

Comment: The first set of code for the list box is executed within the page load and the code to find a selected item is executed within a button click event.  Maybe the problem might be something to do with that

Comment: well then its right. nothing is selected at that point.  Its interesting that you dont then show all that code in your page load code.. only the loading of the listbox.  You dont select a default item after populating so yes -1 no selected item

Comment: is it asp.net ?

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add that to the tags

Comment: You need to put the list binding code in `if(!IsPostBack)` block.

Comment: Oh yeah I knew it was something to do with posting back, thanks it works.  post the answer and ill accept it!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are converting an int to a string & then converting back to an int? Why not just _"int test = lbProjects.SelectedIndex;"_ (not that it is a cause of the problem)

Comment: I've been stuck on this error for days, I messed about with it so much, I will change it back to what you mentioned hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Web Application specifically in ASP.NET `Page_Load` executes every time page is submitted.

So the list Binding code executes during every page_load and that sets the list.SelectedIndex to -1 and the selection made in the UI is lost.

So you need to make sure that the list is re-bind again and maintains the selection.

You need check if page is not posted back before binding list to the datasource. You can do that by following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        String Sql = @" select * from project";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Resources.cString);
        SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Properties.Resources.cString);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        DA.Fill(DS, "Project");
        DataTable DT = DS.Tables["Project"];

        lbProjects.DataValueField = "ProjectID";
        lbProjects.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
        lbProjects.DataSource = DT;
        lbProjects.DataBind();
    }

}
```

This should resolve your issue.